# Google Analytics Real-Time not showing results

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

The following script is not generating activity when cross-checked in `Google Analytics` : `Real-Time` section : `Content` section --

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-475021xx-x', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

where `xx-x` masks the real account code.

The script is placed just before `</head>`

We have upgraded our account to `Universal Analytics`. Google tells us that this is the script to use; directly copied and pasted here (with the masked account code).

On the Google Analytics page, the test page is loaded as an `ACTIVE PAGE`. I click links on the test page to trigger `ga`.

Is there an error in this script? For example, I see on other Stackoverflow posts that `'auto'` is replaced with the real `domain`. But I don't see Google instructions to make that substitution.

Am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: When did you add this bit of code?

Comment: @Mark about 8 hours ago (~ 12:00 CDT)

Comment: Does the overview (not the real time one) show data?

Comment: @Mark No - just checked. The overview page (with a map) reports: "Right now 0 active users on site" Only the test page has the in-line script. No other page on the site has a Google analytics script.

Comment: If it is a new Google Analytics account it can take up to 72 hours for data to start showing up.   If you just added the code to the website it can take between 24 - 48 hours for it to show up.

Comment: @JayGray, any updates with your data?

Comment: @nyuen. Just checked - working perfectly. TY. Real time documents my presence on page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the health of your tag using Google tag assistant, and also check with developer tools whether you can see data being sent to your GA account. Also look in your account under Property > Tracking Info > Tracking Code for the status of your tracking code. But if you are not seeing Real Time data then something could be wrong.

The third parameter in the 'create' method sets the cookie domain. It is optional and with 'auto', it sets the cookie domain to the highest domain level possible. Without it, the cookie domain will be set to the website domain without the www. prefix.

Comment: I checked Property > Tracking Info > Tracking Code. Google reports: "Status: Receiving Data." Uncertain about your instructions re 'auto'. The "highest domain level possible" is good for us. So we should keep "auto' and not specify some part of the domain (i.e. a specific sub directory like http://example.com/public)?

Comment: Check your RT reports again. Remember that you need to be on the site at the same time to see any data.

You can set your cookie domain to just example.com for most intents and purposes. If you set it to a folder then only from that folder would you collect data and not from the main site.

Comment: Roger that. In Chrome am running Google Analytics on one tab and the test page on a second tab. I periodically click a URL on the test page to trigger ga. Nothing yet. WRT 'auto' I'll leave it as-is. I will mark this as answered as soon as something/anything shows up in Google Analytics.

Comment: Thanks, everything looks healthy. I sent in a test event (test_category, test_action, test_label). Do you see that in RT (you would have to check within 30 minutes of me posting this).

Comment: Sorry to have missed the 30 minute window - was called away from computer. Would you retest - I'll stay online.

Comment: It's ok, you can do it yourself, too. My objective is to see if you can see events getting pushed to GA on your site, and not just visits. On your site, I just opened up a console window and entered "ga('send','event','test_category','test_action','test_label')".

Answer (score 5):

I did the same thing as you back then.

Mine started showing data in about 12-24 hours after I put the Google Analytics code.

I suggest waiting for another day then checking if data comes up.

---

Given that this answer can only be verified until we wait for a certain amount of time, please hold off setting this as the correct answer until then.

Comment: roger that. Will check again @ 12:00 CDT Friday.

Comment: I'll let you know tomorrow. Just installed GA today and experiencing this now. I can't believe there's no easily seeable warning about this...

Answer (score 5):

For me, the issue was a dunce move. I have the Google Analytics Opt-out Add-on for Chrome enabled.

What I had to do was go to chrome://extensions/, scroll down to the Extension "Google Analytics Opt-out Add-on (by Google)" and uncheck the box that says, "Enable".

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what my issue was. I'm using google analytics with wordpress. I tried configuring google analytics for my website using plugin called Google Analytics Dashboard for WP (GADWP). This plugin generated a google analytics snippet that looks similarly to the one described in the question:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-475021xx-x', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

However, in Google Analytics console, the suggested snippet looked like this:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-110984887-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-475021xx-x');
</script>
```

It looks like this gtag.js is a new format for the google analytics snippet. So I disabled that wordpress plugin and I manually added the script suggested by Google Analytics to the page.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently fixed the same issue. Please login to your admin dashboard and check the filters.

What I did was to make sure my valid host name filter was the correct one.

If you have copied the custom dashboard from another project or if you had an error in the filter then this would be worth your time to check out.

I have placed the value "domain.com" in the included host names filter.

Let me know if this fixed the issue for you.